# Error en json_encode y json_decode php

Tags: php, json

estoy realizando un web services en php, mi problema es al obtener el resultado de la consulta ya que lo que me devuelve de la url lo que recibo es un un html nose de donde y porque.

Mi código es.

```
$tarjeta = $_POST['tarjeta'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];
        $cuenta = $_POST['radio'];
        // Aca en $JSON recibo como un html no se por que.
        $JSON = file_get_contents("http://localhost/poo/cajero/" . $tarjeta . "/" . $pass . "/" . $cuenta);
// $rs queda en null
        $rs = json_decode($JSON, true);

        echo $rs;
```

```
require "Conexion/CConexion.php";
require "Clases/CCajero.php";

$cajero = new CCajero();
$cuenta = $_GET['cuenta'];
$clave = $_GET['pass'];
$tipocuenta = $_GET['tipo'];
$op = $_GET['op'];
// $rs puede sera como una palabra invalido o como un id
$rs = $cajero->validarIngreso($cuenta, $clave, $tipocuenta);
$respuesta = json_encode($rs);

echo $rs;
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega lo que recibes en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas soy nuevo en esto y creo que por defecto duvuelve asi, por ello para modificarlo a tu gusto y que sea un JSON puedes hacer utilizar lo siguiente

```
$url = 'http://localhost/poo/cajero/';

$obj_tarjeta = array()
$obj_tarjeta['tarjeta'] = $_POST['tarjeta'];
$obj_tarjeta['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$obj_tarjeta['radio'] = $_POST['radio'];

$opciones = array(
            "http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "header" => "Content-type: application/json",
                "content" => json_encode($obj_tarjeta ), # Agregar el contenido definido antes
            ),
        );
# Preparar petición
$contexto = stream_context_create($opciones);

# Hacerla
$res= file_get_contents($url, false, $contexto);
if ($res === false) {
   echo "Error al obtener la data";
   exit;
}

# Resultado JSON obtenido
$res = json_decode($res);
```